# how to create a asynchronous function to return user state after login using Meteor.loginWithPassword()

Tags: javascript, meteor, authentication

i try to create a function that return user state after login with Meteor.loginWithPassword() but it's asynchronous, the function always return undefined, how can i solve that?

```
var state;
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(action.email, action.password,
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      alert('Đăng nhập thất bại')
    } else {
      state = "login success"
    }
  })
  return state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state variable is not a reactive variable, so if value of state update it will not update the spacebar code inside html template.

1. You can solve this problem using any reactivating thing  like Session, reactive var or reactive dict.

   ```
   //Make sure you have install reactive var package
   var state = new ReactiveVar('');
   Template['name'].helpers({
     'getState': function (userId) {
       Meteor.loginWithPassword(action.email, action.password,(err) => {
          if (err) {
               alert('Đăng nhập thất bại')
          } else {
              state.set("login success");
          }
       }) 
       console.log(len.get()); // You will get 2 when response come from   you method call. 
       return state.get(); 
     } 
   });
   ```
2. You can also use spacbar helper from Account UI named 'currentUser'. So your html will be like:

   ```
   {{#if currentUser}}
       <!-- Do something when user is login -->
   {{else}}
       <!-- Do something when user is not login -->
   {{/if}}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Ask a callback argument/parameter to your function which you will call when login is successful

```
function login(action, callback) {

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(action.email, action.password, err => {
        if ( err ) {
            //...
        } else {
          callback('login success');
        }
    });

 }
```